# Sqlalchemy column_property based on other rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the models `expense` and `income` which respectively have the many-to-many relationships `refunds` and `expenses`. I want to create a column_property on the `expense` table which is called `refunded_amount` and is filled according to the following pseudo code (with expenses filtered by the same `refund.income_id`):

```py
expenses = [exp1, exp2]
payment = income.amount
for exp in expenses:
    amt = exp.amount
    if amt <= payment:
        exp.refunded_amount += amt
        payment -= amt
    else:
        exp.refunded_amount = payment
        payment = 0
```

How do I convert this to sqlalchemy and include it in the select statement for the `refunded_amount` column_property? These are the models currently, but like this `refunded_amount` of each expense contains the total of all expenses related to that particular income.

```py
refund_table = Table(
    "refund", Base.metadata,
    Column("expense_id", Integer, ForeignKey("expense.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("income_id", Integer, ForeignKey("income.id"), primary_key=True)
)


class Income(Base):
    __tablename__ = "income"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Float)
    refund = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    expenses = relationship("Expense", secondary=refund_table,
                            back_populates="refunds")


class Expense(Base):
    __tablename__ = "expense"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    refunds = relationship("Income", secondary=refund_table,
                           back_populates="expenses")

    refunded_amount = column_property(
        select(
            [func.sum(Income.amount)],
            and_(
                refund_table.c.expense_id == id,
                refund_table.c.income_id == Income.id
            ),
            refund_table
        ).label("refunded_amount")
    )
```

Importantly, if possible, I would like use declarative and avoid falling back to a classical Python `@property` in which I could use the object's current session, because, as stated in the [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-plain-descriptor):

> The plain descriptor approach is useful as a last resort, but is less performant in the usual case than both the hybrid and column property approaches, in that it needs to emit a SQL query upon each access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just take the minimum of `Expense.amount` and `sum(Income.amount)` that returns the desired result:

```py
refunded_amount = column_property(
    select(
        [func.min(amount, func.sum(Income.amount))],
        and_(
            refund_table.c.expense_id == id,
            refund_table.c.income_id == Income.id
        ),
        refund_table
    ).label("refunded_amount")
)
```